# Libgdx json file initial game values

Tags: java, json, file, libgdx

Quick question.

In my code I have the storing of my game values to Json. How would I do something where the first time they enter the game it sets the players values to the default base values. I have a method that has these values set that I can call and then use my save method? But I need a method that checks if its the first time the game has been run.. And if its the first time somehow create the json file to save to later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Libgdx you should use [FileHandle](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html):

```
FileHandle valuesFile = Gdx.files.internal("values.json");
if (!valuesFile.exists()) {
   createJsonValuesFile();
}
```

I would suggest you to check(and create) it prior the actual game starts, for example, during the loading screen setup.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
public class Game
{
    final int COINS_DEFAULT = 0;
    final String PLAYER_NAME_DEFAULT = "PlayerName";

    ...

    File userInfoJSON = new File("/filepath");
    if (userInfoJSON == null)
    {
         resetToDefaultsThenSaveToJSON();
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution most probably would not work for Libgdx. BTW, why do you use the C-style curly braces?)) In Java braces stay at the same line [Java code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#431)

Comment: AFAIK, braces being in the same line or at new line is just a preference, rather than being belong to a language code convention. I always code like this in Java, and I rarely code in C.

Comment: Also, this is just a pseudo code. If you have anything to add, please let us know.

Comment: yeah, I have) you may see the answer below.
Braces are really arguable topic, after all.